# How to display selected taxonomies by their parent

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy as 'services' and custom post type as 'portfolio'. What I would like to do is; I want to list all the selected services under their parent taxonomy in single page.

This is what I would like to achieve:

- Design (parent - not selected): web, graphic, print (selected child taxonomies)
- Development (parent - not selected): app, game, web (selected child taxonomies)

And here is my code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'services' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  $parent = get_term_by('id', $term->parent, 'services');
  $parent_obj = get_term($parent->term_id, 'services');
  $parent_name = $parent_obj->name;

  echo $parent_name . ': ' . $term->name . '<br>';
}
```

[image]

This is how it looks now.

[image]

This is how I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so hard, but some PHP coding will be needed this time. Here's the code that will do the trick (assuming that there are only 2 levels in that hierarchy):

```
$post_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'services' );
$terms = array();

foreach ( $post_terms as $term ) {
    if ( $term->parent ) {
        if ( ! array_key_exists( $term->parent, $terms ) ) {
            $terms[ $term->parent ] = array(
                'term' => get_term( $term->parent, 'services' ),
                'children' => array()
            );
        }
        $terms[ $term->parent ]['children'][] = $term;
    } else {
        if ( ! array_key_exists( $term->term_id, $terms ) ) {
            $terms[ $term->term_id ] = array(
                'term' => $term,
                'children' => array()
            );
        }
    }
}

foreach ( $terms as $term_info ) {
    echo $term_info['term']->name;
    if ( ! empty($term_info['children']) ) {
        echo ': ';
        foreach ( $term_info['children'] as $i => $child ) {
            if ( $i ) echo ', ';
            echo $child->name;
        }
    }
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```